# Every page with extends reloads javascript (and re-establishes ws connection)

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Good day,

I'm a little stuck with one problem and somehow cannot find a solution.

I have base template and two templates which are extending the base one. The base template includes websocket.js file which is establishing WebSocket connection when the user opens a page. Problem is that when he clicks on some link which leads to some child page, the browser is reloading all static files, including websocket.js what leads to disconnect/reconnect of WebSocket connection.

Question how can I avoid such reloads. Should avoid using extends and move to jQuery style dynamic page updates without any reloads or can I keep javascript WebSocket object somewhere in global and do not establish a new connection if this object is not undefined (i do not know how to do that as well).

websocket.js is simple:

```
var websocketServerLocation = 'ws://' + window.location.host +
    '/ws/dashboard/';

function start(websocketServerLocation) {
    ws = new WebSocket(websocketServerLocation);
    ws.onmessage = function (e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        drawDashboard(data);
    };
    ws.onclose = function () {
        // Try to reconnect in 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function () {
            start(websocketServerLocation)
        }, 5000);
    };
}

start(websocketServerLocation);
```

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "websocket.js" %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'child1' %}">child1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'child2' %}">child2</a>
     ....
</html>
```

Some "child":

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django treats every templates as new page or request eventhough they extend the same base template. So it will not be possible to keep the base template. In some other ways you can have everything running via jQuery and ajax to get your job done.